# S#arp Lite with ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, s#arp-architecture, s#arp

Can [S#arp Lite](https://github.com/codai/Sharp-Lite) and [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) be used in combinations?

I love the S#arp Lite as a very simplified version of S#arp Architecture, focused on DDD concepts, nice use of Repository pattern, etc.

At the same time, I also like the ServiceStack's way of developing REST services as opposed to WCF or WebApi.

Is there any example, where these two fantastic things are used together? Will it really make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really not that complicated and not really needing of a sample.

SS will be your "services" and with them, use Request and Response objects to receive and send with SS.

Also, you don't really need S# when using SS. SS has it's own abstractions for Entities and has ORMLite for data access. I do not recommend the use of the repository pattern anymore and your ORM is your data abstraction. With IQueryable, there is a lot you can do without needing a repository.

My everyday stack now consists of AngularJs, TypeScript, ASP.NET MVC, ServiceStack, ORMLite (for lightning fast querying, breaking large object graphs into SQL Views), and occasionally NHibernate or Entity Framework depending on client request. MVC serves up pages that do not require a lot of server interaction or where a round trip does not matter (e.g. Contact Us, About, etc). SS handles all requests from the front end for data.

S# and S# Lite were great when they came out, they helped a lot of people understand the basics of DDD and separations of concerns. Unfortunately in a lot of cases using it was like using a jack hammer to pound a nail in the wall. It introduced complexity into projects where it really wasn't needed.

As it stands, I no longer find S# or S# Lite as useful as they once were for the type of development I do.

Comment: Thanks Alec for providing your perspective. I understand that it really doesn't make sense to combine things just because you like them. :). After using S# for couple of projects, I also now realized and hence agree with you on the complexity aspect.

Comment: I still have many S# projects in the wild and they are still going strong. But with me moving more to a front-end first style of development, even for enterprise applications, I feel I don't need S# anymore. I still find some of the aspects very helpful, such as the base entity class (especially for nHibernate), but I like using OrmLite with SQL a lot better. I do have to manage the object graph more, but it is really not that bad.